# use of header function

Tags: php

i want to delete data from database by clicking a link named "Delete".I want to do it,just by clicking not after refreshing the page. My table and another code including links one,is on a page named "editordeletedata" and the mysql query is on another page named "delete". For this i want to use header function in my delete page. But it shows:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php everyday site tutorials\delete.php:2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php everyday site tutorials\delete.php on line 13

Please tell me the correct use of header function or any other way.

editordelete page: contain a link named "Delete"

delete page :

```
<p> <title>delete</title> </p>
<?php
    include "include.php";
?>

<?php

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $order = "DELETE FROM employee WHERE id='$_GET[id]'";
        mysql_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
    }
    header("Location: editordeletedata.php");         

?>
```

Comment: Please reformat your question. Its not properly readable in this form.

Comment: The problem most certainly arises from your ambient code. You cannot say `header` after you already printed output. Either say `header` before you start printing anything, or enable output buffering.

Comment: Also, **never** put `$_GET[id]` naked into an SQL query. (And it should be `$_GET['id']`.)

Comment: next time i will do@kingcrunch

Comment: i just can't understand what was there i had printed output. Before calling header function, there just have an include file and some deleting query.@kerrek

Comment: i am using dreamwaver 5, it appearing syntax error if i use ($_GET['id'])@kerrek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something is being printed before header function call. If nothing apparently then it must be a space. delete all spaces being printed. convert it into hex format to check where are those spaces creating problem.

Comment: i just can't understand what was there i had printed befor calling it. Before calling header function, there just have an include file and some deleting query.i don't know how to convert hex format@MLS